# Reference a cell relative to another cell Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working with a dataset like this:

```
Sheet1
Term    Multiplier
Term1   M1
Term2   M2
Term3   M3
Term4   M4
Term5   M5

Sheet2
TermA       TermB       TermC       Score
=Sheet1!A2  =Sheet1!A3  =Sheet1!A5  (M2+M3+M5)
=Sheet1!A3                          (M3)
=Sheet1!A1  =Sheet1!A2              (M1+M2)
=Sheet1!A2  =Sheet1!A4              (M2+M4)
```

Sheet1 has a static list of Terms and its Multipliers.
Sheet2's list items can have up to 3 references to a Term in Sheet1.

What I am trying to do is calculate a score in Sheet2. It should find the Terms that are in the row, look up their multipliers, and add those up.
However, I am struggling to figure out how I can reference the multipliers.
Basically, I need to go through the references at TermA, B and C and look at the value next to the target of that reference.
I have found the functions FORMULATEXT, INDIRECT and ADDRESS, which offer part of the functionality that I need, but I can't figure out how to combine them (if this is even the way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use for instance:

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$6,2,false),0) + IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$6,2,false),0) + IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$6,2,false),0)

Comment: This works, VLOOKUP is what I needed, it took me a while to figure I really did need the false in there, although the 0 does not seem to be required.

Comment: @Vasilis, the 0 is for when a column is blank. so if your term c is not there, it won't error.

Comment: @NaziA Yes I realise that, but I left it out and it still works, even with an entry that has no Terms (all 3 are blank), it will resolve as 0.

Answer (score 1):

This could be simpler if `INDIRECT` works with `ARRAYFORMULA`, but it doesn't, so one thing I thought is to manually calculate the pointer using `INDIRECT` per cell then add them after appending `Sheeet1!` to locate the values of those pointers in `Sheet1`.

#### Formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(CONCAT("Sheet1!", VLOOKUP(A2, Sheet1!A:B, 2)))) +
IFERROR(INDIRECT(CONCAT("Sheet1!", VLOOKUP(B2, Sheet1!A:B, 2)))) +
IFERROR(INDIRECT(CONCAT("Sheet1!", VLOOKUP(C2, Sheet1!A:B, 2))))
```

#### Data:

[image: data]

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: I tried this but there seems to be something wrong with the INDIRECT syntax (it sticks the value of the cell at the end of the string, which is an invalid cell reference), but VLOOKUP looks like the function I needed.